# macOS How to read Pages/Numbers file in command line?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface

macOS How to read Pages/Numbers file in command line ?

I have userd 'cat'

`cat /Users/administrator/Downloads/test.pages`

but get:

`????(??#?-QEQEQEQEQEQEQEQE?kYe??Ȍ?"8?,?9A?i;??1]?????=.SE[????Sqs-?,?iY??3]]QEQEQEQEQEQEQEQE??????(??(??(??(??(??(??(??(??(??(??????(??(??(??(??`

---

addtional

I can use cat to watch .md file

Comment: Used `cat` on what?  ... That output looks like `cat` was possibly used on a binary file?

Answer (score 0):

Pages/Numbers files are .zip archives of binary files, not text files. In order to read them on the command line, you'll need a special tool, though I don't believe one exists at the moment

Comment: so how dect tools get the sensitive words from pages?